# How can I make a login page that saves the data entered?

Tags: javascript, html, css, authentication

I know how to make the webpage itself but have no idea how to make the entered data get saved inside the page. Any tips?

Comment: you need to send that data to a backend and then store it in a data base, if you know JS check mongoDB and Node

Comment: Is this easy to do? I do not know the programs you have listed.

Comment: a few months of practice, check youtube, learn about API's

Comment: Ok, I will do what you suggested. Youtube is useless for this topic. Believe me, I have looked and looked. Thanks.

Comment: Use a server side language like PHP for your backend code that posts the form data to a database. Make sure to search sanitation and cleansing of your form data, do not cut corners on sanitation of your form data! Look into PDO connections to a database! Creating a truly secure login system is no easy task. SSL injection is a huge risk and coding a database login that protects against the many risks involved can be tough. This is why I suggest using something like google api.

Answer (score 0):

You need a backend language like node Js , php , golang etc... to process the data

Then a database to store the data like mysql , oracle , mongodb etc..

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use javascript but you would have to use other programs other than just your coding software because there is no way to save data in vanilla js

Answer (score 0):

In general, in a web service structure, data is stored in a database. However, in the case of browser-dependent temporary data such as authentication token, it is stored in the browser's cache, typically html5 localStorage.

so, Use HTML5 local storage.
(Not stored on the page,
The data is stored in the browser.)

http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

```
var foo = localStorage.getItem("bar");
// ...
localStorage.setItem("bar", foo);
…could be rewritten to use square bracket syntax instead:

var foo = localStorage["bar"];
// ...
localStorage["bar"] = foo;
```